# CSS3 hover on icon element

Tags: javascript, html, css

html code..

```
       <div>
          <ul class="social-icon">
            <li><a href="#" class="social-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

css code..

```
.social-icon {
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          position: fixed;
        }
        .social-icon li {
          list-style: none;
          display: inline-block;
          float: left;
        }
        .social-icon a {
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 18px;
          line-height: 38px;
          width: 35px;
          border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
          border-left: 0;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .social-icon a.social-facebook {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: scale(2);
          -moz-transform: scale(2);
          -o-transform: scale(2);
          -ms-transform: scale(2);
          transform: scale(2);
          -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
          -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
          -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
        }
        .social-icon a.social-facebook:hover {
          background-color: #0e39d8;
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          -moz-transform: scale(1);
          -o-transform: scale(1);
          -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
          -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }
        .social-icon a:first-child {
          border-left: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
        }
        .social-icon a i {
          color: #d2d2db;
        }
```

The problem is that.. I need one static icon and one hover icon... my static icon opacity was-0.. but i want to show static icon in same position and when hover the icon gonna be down and up.......please help me..... the fb icon not shown when hover its show.
[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/)
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: For this kind of question, I suggest to use http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar to play a bit with a real scenario.

Comment: @user3841751 - its a little hard to understand what you're after, perhaps provide an illustration?

Comment: this is what you want? http://jsbin.com/retogiqe/1/edit

Comment: No @KheemaPandey ...opacity will be 0 and scale-2 i want a mask of the icon.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/avAdq)?

Comment: @Tushar Bro mejhe kus aisa hi cahiya tha.. lekin ye serf in ho raha hai out nahi ho raha ....mujhe dono hi cahiye...please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/avAdq)

I have done it using CSS3 keyframes

CSS

```
.social-icon a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: 0.3s popIn;
  -moz-animation: 0.3s popIn;
   animation: 0.3s popIn;
   background-color: #0e39d8;
   }     
@-webkit-keyframes popIn
{
  0%   {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}  
  50%   {-webkit-transform: scale(2)}
  100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1); background-color: #0e39d8;
          opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes popIn
{
  0%   {-moz-transform: scale(1)}
  50%   {-moz-transform: scale(2)}
  100% {-moz-transform: scale(1); background-color: #0e39d8;
          opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes popIn
{
  0%   {transform: scale(1)}
  50%   {transform: scale(2)}
  100% {transform: scale(1); background-color: #0e39d8;
          opacity: 1;}
}
```

Comment: thanx bro...little bit problem..Jab icon par hover hoga tab popin hoga aur jab icon se mouse hat jayega tab popout go jayega. Thanx

Comment: can you give me your fb id please??

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is:
create a tiny DIV element,
set a background to it using CSS (your image).
then create a :hover setting in CSS with a different background.

Comment: I don't want use any image only icon font. Please view this http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/

Answer (score 0):

Why you set the opacity 0, that make your image trasparent.
if you want to see the static image you have to set opacity not 0 but 1 for see the image.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you want but give effect your varinat think that my version will help you
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WdCvv/8/)

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WdCvv/13/)

[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/24/)

```
      .social-icon a {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.social-icon a:hover {
    background-color: #0e39d8;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bro @Alex Wilson i use scale method...this thing doesn't suitable for this effect..just like this..http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/avAdq....with up and down.

Comment: Thank bro for your support.....But i don't need look like this variants. Again thanx for your support. Please see this. http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/avAdq

Comment: )) Here and wanted to write this way but I'm ahead